# How to fix error code 500 when using HttpURLConnection GET request with header? Header is not being sent

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I am trying to send a GET request with a header, but the header is not being send and I am receiving error code 500. ttps://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2019-09-01.

I have tried several variations such as the depreciated apache, HttpURLConnection, and volley. I always end up getting error code 500. I have added the permissions in manifest. I tested the API GET request on Postman and it works fine as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/n2tv2e

```
public void buttonHandler(View v)
{
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2019-09-01");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("X-RapidAPI-Key", "jkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkj");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");


        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        textView.setText(line);
        con.disconnect();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I want the json file as shown here: http://prntscr.com/n2tv2e

Answer (score -1):

You need to add header like this

```
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost( "URL" );
 post.addHeader( "Key" , "Value" );
```

Comment: I am trying to do a GET request though. Also isnt HttpPost deprecated?

Comment: Indeed you're right, its been a while i worked on android, anyway, i think you need to use volley take a look at this https://androidclarified.com/android-volley-example/  specially the section "Volley request with Custom Headers"

Comment: You don't need to use either the Apache HTTP client, which is what this appears to be, or volley. They do not have magical properties. You need to look at the server log to see what the actual error was. The whole point of 500 is to conceal that from you as a possible attacker.

Comment: @user207421 I am curious how would go about checking the server log? Where can I learn more about this. I get his response from the server which tells I was not able to send the key which I was able to through Volley. https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/2019-09-01